# Method querying SQLite database taking forever to finish

Tags: java, performance, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with a table that has ~90000 row.. Here is the method that is taking too long to finish..

```
void intilizeAyaHighlighShapes() {
        ayaShapes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<AyaShape>>();
        ArrayList<AyaShape> ayaRowsHighlight = new ArrayList<AyaShape>(); // contains the highligh shapes of a specific aya for all its rows

        int tmpAya = 1, tmpLineMin = 0, tmpLineMax = 0;
        int maxLeft = 0, maxRight = 0, maxTop = 0, maxBottom = 0;

        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ayahinfo_800.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor cursor = null;

        while (tmpAya < Database.AyatNumberInSura[suraIndex]) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(line_number) FROM glyphs WHERE(sura_number=" + Integer.toString(suraIndex + 1) + " AND ayah_number=" + Integer.toString(tmpAya) + ")",
                    null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            tmpLineMin = cursor.getInt(0);

            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(line_number) FROM glyphs WHERE(sura_number=" + Integer.toString(suraIndex + 1) + " AND ayah_number=" + Integer.toString(tmpAya) + ")",
                    null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            tmpLineMax = cursor.getInt(0);


            for (int i = tmpLineMin; i <= tmpLineMax; i++) {
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(max_x) FROM glyphs WHERE (sura_number=" + Integer.toString(suraIndex + 1) + " AND ayah_number=" + Integer.toString(tmpAya)
                        + " AND line_number=" + Integer.toString(i) + ")", null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                maxRight = cursor.getInt(0);

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(min_x) FROM glyphs WHERE (sura_number=" + Integer.toString(suraIndex + 1) + " AND ayah_number=" + Integer.toString(tmpAya)
                        + " AND line_number=" + Integer.toString(i) + ")", null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                maxLeft = cursor.getInt(0);

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(max_y) FROM glyphs WHERE (sura_number=" + Integer.toString(suraIndex + 1) + " AND ayah_number=" + Integer.toString(tmpAya)
                        + " AND line_number=" + Integer.toString(i) + ")", null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                maxBottom = cursor.getInt(0);

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(min_y) FROM glyphs WHERE (sura_number=" + Integer.toString(suraIndex + 1) + " AND ayah_number=" + Integer.toString(tmpAya)
                        + " AND line_number=" + Integer.toString(i) + ")", null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                maxTop = cursor.getInt(0);



                ayaRowsHighlight.add(new AyaShape(maxLeft, maxRight, maxTop, maxBottom));
            }

            ayaShapes.add(ayaRowsHighlight);
            ayaRowsHighlight.clear();
            tmpAya++;

        }





        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }
```

What could be the parts of this code that is making it take so long?
Should I write here the purpose of this code?

Comment: @Nambari 2 mins and it still didnt finish!

Comment: ... just curious, how long does it take to finish?

Comment: Something like 8-10 minutes..

Comment: How's just the sql portion of it performing against the db? Have you tried to get the data set with just one hit against the db?

Comment: @vector I didnt totally understand.. Do you mean I should try to query 1 time the db? if so, it does it instantly..

Comment: right, get the all the data you need with one query and then process the results ( if that's a possibility )

Answer (score 0):

You could simply combine multiple queries with the same WHERE condition:

```sql
SELECT MIN(line_number), MAX(line_number)
 FROM glyphs
 WHERE sura_number = ? AND ayah_number = ?
```

and:

```sql
SELECT MAX(max_x), MIN(min_x), MAX(max_y), MIN(min_y)
 FROM glyphs
 WHERE sura_number = ? AND ayah_number = ? AND line_number = ?
```

However, your algorithm does not actually require that `tmpLineMin` and `tmpLineMax` are known *before* the individual glyph bounds are handled. So you can speed it up further by using a single query and then stepping through the result rows (one per line number):

```sql
SELECT line_number, MAX(max_x), MIN(min_x), MAX(max_y), MIN(min_y)
 FROM glyphs
 WHERE sura_number = ? AND ayah_number = ?
 GROUP BY line_number
 ORDER BY line_number
```